Azure DevOps Yaml - how to set global variables from parameters?
We have pipelines that are mostly started manually, and the user can set a various options:

The above parameters are defined in the top level YAML, like this:
parameters:
  - name: reasonForManualBuild
    displayName: Reason for manual run
    type: string
    default: ''

  - name: cleanAgents
    displayName: Wipe agents before build
    type: boolean
    default: false
    values:
    - false
    - true

  - name: buildSoftware
    displayName: Build software
    type: boolean
    default: true
    values:
    - false
    - true

  - name: runAnalysis
    displayName: Run static code analysis
    type: boolean
    default: true
    values:
    - false
    - true

This works very well, but, at the moment, I'm passing most of the parameters to templates that call templates with the same parameters etc. Not very nice.
It would be great if I could define global variables from these parameters, like this:
variables:
  - name: cleanAgents
    value: ${{ parameters.cleanAgents }}

  - name: buildSoftware
    value: ${{ parameters.buildSoftware }}

and then use them within the templates, as $(cleanagents), $(buildSoftware), etc.
As far as I understand the documentation, this should work, but it doesn't, when I run the pipeline, they appear empty.
As an alternative I tried passing parameter objects, which doesn't seem to work either.
Am I making a mistake, or is there a correct way to do it, or is it just not possible?
The main product pipeline, where I'm just calling the product "Foo":
parameters:
  - name: reasonForManualBuild
    displayName: Reason for manual run
    type: string
    default: ''

  - name: cleanAgents
    displayName: Wipe agents before build
    type: boolean
    default: false
    values:
    - false
    - true

  - name: buildSoftware
    displayName: Build software
    type: boolean
    default: true
    values:
    - false
    - true

  - name: runAnalysis
    displayName: Run static code analysis
    type: boolean
    default: true
    values:
    - false
    - true

  - name: runUnitTests
    displayName: Run unit tests
    type: boolean
    default: true
    values:
    - false
    - true

  - name: runFunctionalTests
    displayName: Run functional tests
    type: boolean
    default: false
    values:
    - false
    - true

  - name: continueOnError
    displayName: Continue on error
    type: boolean
    default: false
    values:
    - false
    - true

  - name: productVersion
    displayName: Product version number
    type: string
    default: 5.0.0.1

name: QEC-${{ parameters.productVersion }}-$(Date:yyMMdd)$(Rev:rr)

variables:
  - name: productName
    value: FOO

  - name: productVersion
    value: ${{ parameters.productVersion }}

  - name: cleanAgents
    value: ${{ parameters.cleanAgents }}

  - name: buildSoftware
    value: ${{ parameters.buildSoftware }}

  - name: runAnalysis
    value: ${{ parameters.runAnalysis }}    

  - name: runUnitTests
    value: ${{ parameters.runUnitTests }} 

  - name: runFunctionalTests
    value: ${{ parameters.runFunctionalTests }} 
    
  - name: continueOnError
    value: ${{ parameters.continueOnError }} 

resources:
  repositories:
    # skipping resources block as not relevant here

extends:
  template: /BaseTest-pipeline.yml

The BaseTest-pipeline.yml:
stages:
  - stage: stage_Test
    displayName: "Build $(productName), no analysis" 
    jobs:
    - job: jobShow
      displayName: 'Job with $(productName)' 
      steps:
      - script: |
          echo "productName    = $(productName)"
          echo "productVersion = $(productVersion)"
          echo "cleanAgents    = $(cleanAgents)"

shows, as displayname: Job with $(productName)
But then correctly shows three variables, including productName, correctly:
"productName    = FOO"
"productVersion = 5.0.0.1"
"cleanAgents    = False"


EDIT:
I attempted on my side, and it can work fine to use the parameters to set global variables. See below example as reference.

The YAML files.


The file azure-pipelines.yml
# azure-pipelines.yml

parameters:
- name: param01
  type: boolean
  default: true
- name: param02
  type: boolean
  default: false

variables:
- name: varParam01
  value: ${{ parameters.param01 }}
- name: varParam02
  value: ${{ parameters.param02 }}

steps:
- script: |
    echo "This steps is from the main YAML azure-pipelines.yml"
    echo "param01 = ${{ parameters.param01 }}"
    echo "param01 = ${{ parameters.param02 }}"
    echo "varParam01 = $(varParam01)"
    echo "varParam02 = $(varParam02)"

- template: /templates/temp-steps01.yml


The template YAML /templates/temp-steps01.yml
# /templates/temp-steps01.yml

steps:
- script: |
    echo "This steps is from template YAML temp-steps01.yml"
    echo "varParam01 = $(varParam01)"
    echo "varParam02 = $(varParam02)"

- template: /templates/temp-steps02.yml


The nested template YAML /templates/temp-steps02.yml
# /templates/temp-steps02.yml

steps:
- script: |
    echo "This steps is from the nested template YAML temp-steps02.yml"
    echo "varParam01 = $(varParam01)"
    echo "varParam02 = $(varParam02)"




The result.




EDIT_2:
For boolean type parameter, the available values are only true and false. So, you do not need to use the 'values' key to provide a list of all the available values. But you must provide the default value (true or false) using the 'default' key. Just like as the sample I shared above.
For the string type parameter, you are correct, you can provide an empty value to the 'default' key.
When users manually trigger the pipeline, for the boolean type parameter, the users can manually check or uncheck the option on the UI to change the value to be true (check) or false (uncheck). For the string type parameter, the users can manually enter the the value in the field on the UI.
After users manually set/enter the parameter values and click "Run" on the UI to trigger a new run, the pipeline gets compiled with the parameter values set/entered by users.
See below example.

The main YAML azure-pipelines.yml. Updated based on above sample.

# azure-pipelines.yml

parameters:
- name: param01
  type: boolean
  default: true
- name: param02
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: param03
  type: string
  default: ''

variables:
- name: varParam01
  value: ${{ parameters.param01 }}
- name: varParam02
  value: ${{ parameters.param02 }}
- name: varParam03
  value: ${{ parameters.param03 }}

steps:
. . .


Manually trigger the pipeline.




EDIT_3:

The azure-pipelines.yml
parameters:
- name: param01
  type: boolean
  default: true
- name: param02
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: param03
  type: string
  default: ''

variables:
- name: varParam01
  value: ${{ parameters.param01 }}
- name: varParam02
  value: ${{ parameters.param02 }}
- name: varParam03
  value: ${{ parameters.param03 }}

extends:
  template: /templates/temp-steps01.yml


The /templates/temp-steps01.yml
extends:
  template: /templates/temp-steps02.yml


The /templates/temp-steps02.yml
steps:
- script: |
    echo "This steps is from the nested template YAML temp-steps02.yml"
    echo "varParam01 = $(varParam01)"
    echo "varParam02 = $(varParam02)"
    echo "varParam03 = $(varParam03)"


Result.




EDIT_4:
# azure-pipelines.yml

variables:
  myVar01: '123'

stages:
- stage: A
  variables:
    myVar02: '456'
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    variables:
      myVar03: '789'
    steps:
    . . .
  - job: A2
    variables:
    steps:
    . . .

- stage: B
  . . .


The variable myVar01 is a global variable that can be available for all the stages and jobs in this pipeline.

The variable myVar02 is a stage-level variable defined in stage A. It can be available only within stage A, and not available for stage B.

The variable myVar03 is a job-level variable defined in job A1. It can be available only within job A1, and not available for job A2 and stage B.



EDIT_5:
The '$(varName)' is a runtime expression that is evaluated at runtime before tasks start running. So, it generally is used as the input of tasks.
The stage name and job name are evaluated at compile-time before runtime. So, when using the expression '$(varName)' on stage name and job name, it will return the expression itself.
You need to use the template expression "${{ variables.varName }}" to pass pipeline variables to the stage name and job name, because this expression is evaluated at compile-time.
However, when using template expression to pass pipeline variables in template YAML, only some of the predefined variables are available, the user-defined variables are not available. All the variables you defined under the 'variables' key are user-defined variables.



Yes, but I have I'm calling templates that are calling templates. And I don't want to pass the parameters from template to template to template.

@HaraldJ, I attempted and it can work fine to use the parameters to set global variables. See the example under EDIT.

Thanks, Bright!
I guess the difference is that, in your example, the parameters are fixed, and the values available at compile-time.
My parameters are defined by the user, and I guess the pipeline has already be compiled at that stage.

@HaraldJ, What do you mean "My parameters are defined by the user"?

@HaraldJ, In my example, the values are not fixed, it also can be changed. I just set the default values to the parameters.

Just edited the original question to show how the option parameters shown in my screenshot are defined. It doesn't seem to work that way.

@HaraldJ, I have provided more suggestions in my above answer. See EDIT_2.

Thanks, Bright! So it works for you, and I must be doing something wrong somewhere to have empty variables. Will do a lot more digging!

@HaraldJ, Post the detailed YAML content of your template YAML and nested template YAML, so that we can help you to check the possible issue in the template YAML files.

it is a lot of code. The only difference I can see at the moment is that I use short product-pipelines that us extends with a base pipeline shared by all projects. The product YAML passes all the parameters to the base YAML - that's where my pretty long parameter passing starts.

@HaraldJ, I also tried to use the extends key to call the template YAML and nested template YAML, all can work fine. In my '/templates/temp-steps02.yml' it also can fetch the correct variable values.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@HaraldJ, See EDIT_3 in my above answer.

@HaraldJ, Check if you had defined variables with the same variable-names but empty values in the template YAML and nested template YAML.

Thanks, @bright-ran-msft! I'm trying to find out where the differences are. I'm also using variables in templates, and I have a block of resources: before variables:.  Can't see why it would make a difference, but something must be different.

done that, there are no empty variables with the same name.
Just moved the variables block in front of the resources, and commented out the variable templates, still the same.

@HaraldJ, How about move the resources block to the main YAML file azure-pipelines.yml of the pipeline?

That's where it already is.
Even if I define a variable as constant at the top level Foo-pipeline.yml, as in   - name: productName     value: FOO, it appears empty at the next level.

@HaraldJ, It's indeed odd. Can you start a new pipeline with a simple template for testing. Just like the example in my answer. First to ensure the simple demo can work as expected in your Azure DevOps project.

just replaced my the base pipeline I'm extending to with a very simple  one that just shows the variables I want to see. And it works!
The only difference I can see is that I'm not passing all the parameters to the base pipeline. And that doesn't make any difference, just tried. it.
Could it be variable scope? All the variables that appear empty are within stages and jobs.

@HaraldJ, variables defined within stages and jobs are not global variables. The stage-level variables can be only available for the stage where to define the variables. Similar, the job-level variables can be only available for the job where to define the variables.

@HaraldJ, The global variables should be defined outside of the stages and jobs, and generally should be defined in the main/top YAML file of the pipeline.

the global variables are defined outside and well before any stages.
Just added a test stage and job to the test base-pipeline, with an interesting result:
displayName: 'Job with $(productName)' shows just that, and doesn't expand the variable. But a step within that job, echo "productName    = $(productName)", does expand the variable correctly, and shows the product name correctly.

@HaraldJ,  What does you test demo look like? Can you post the detailed YAML? And also see EDIT_4 for variables in different levels.

how can I do that here, with only 560 characters without formatting in a comment?

@HaraldJ, Post the YAML to you top post of the question. Do not post it in the comment field. You can edit your first post to add more information on this case.

Added code to the edit of my original question.

@HaraldJ, The '$(varName)' is a runtime expression that is evaluated at runtime before tasks start running. The stage name and job name are evaluated at compile-time before runtime. For more details, see EDIT_5.

Thank you! I had hoped that there is a way around passing parameters to templates that pass them on to templates (that pass them on to templates), but variables in DevOps YAML don't seem to be a solution, so I guess I'll stay with my lists of parameters!
